# Terminal 'last' command doesn't display login history

Tags: macos, terminal, shell

The `last` command in Terminal (on Mac OS X 10.11.2) is supposed to display a list of login history. However, when I type it in, all I get is

```
user$ last

wtmp begins Mon Jan 11 13:17
user$ last user

wtmp begins Mon Jan 11 13:17
...
```

The date printed is the current date and time. Is there something wrong with my system? Might it have something to do with the fact that I have a brewed bash 4.3 in `/usr/local/bin`?

Since `last` doesn't work, are there any alternatives? I'm trying to write a shell script that can figure out how long it's been since the login before the current session.

Comment: `sudo last` make any difference?

Comment: Ahh, yes, that did work. I did some research and discovered the problem is that I didn't have read-access to `private/var/log/system.log`. Thank you!

Comment: Lots of things act differently with & without `sudo`, it's something to try if a system-type command like that doesn't work, as long as you ***know*** what it should do, and it doesn't have the potential to erase any important files or drives that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I didn't have read access to the log file `/private/var/log/system.log`, so `last` didn't display anything. I just have to run `sudo chmod 644 /private/var/log/system.log`.